# Batch Enqueue using WMQ Transport with Mule ESB

Tags: xml, jms, mule, ibm-mq, esb

My requirement is to read a csv and send multiple xml messages to IBM mq.

The xmls created from csv are to be sent in a single batch or transaction.
Reason being the system reading these messages is not idempotent, and in case some xml messages are sent across and the remaining fail. I need to persist the failed xml messages for manual re-processing.

Would be great if someone can point me a feature where multiple xml messages can be en-queued as a single batch.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have conflicting requirements.

Sending the messages in a batch is easy.  You put them all under syncpoint, then issue `COMMIT`.  As long as there are not more messages than the queue depth or transaction UOW limits can hold, you are fine.

Receiving them in a batch is another matter altogether.  IBM MQ has message grouping and the `BIND_ON_OPEN` parameter to make sure all affiliated messages go to the same place and can be accounted for.

So far, this is all easy and based on options in the basic MQ API or JMS API.  The greater issue I see is the statement that "the system reading these messages is not idempotent" which is a fancy way of saying that it does not detect and gracefully handle dupe messages.  That's kind of a problem with any async messaging transport unless XA is used.  It must either gracefully handle dupe messages or use a transaction coordinator to ensure there are no dupe messages.  I'll assume for the moment that you are using 2-phase commit so this requirement is being met.

The other potential issue arises from "I need to persist the failed xml messages for manual re-processing."  Not sure what "manual reprocessing" means here.  IBM MQ will persist the messages, just mark it as such when you `PUT` it on the queue.  When the QMgr is restored the messages will be delivered.  However this statement seems to hint at a High Availability or Disaster Recovery requirement such that the messages are replicated.

So the short answer is to choose persistence as message property when putting the message and to do so under 2-phase commit.

The longer answer depends on what the references to idempotence and recovery actually allude to.  If there are requirements here you'll need to add detail to the question.

Comment: Appreciate your response and this does give me some insight from IBM MQ context. However i was looking at a solution using Mules ESB components. Finally ended up using a VM-Queue and a WMQ together to make things transactional.